# Is there a way to filter addresses per role in ActiveMQ Artemis web console?

Tags: activemq-artemis

In the ActiveMQ Artemis web console we have many addresses for different users.

We would like to view only the addresses that belong to a specific user with a specific role. Is this achievable to config in `management.xml`?

Comment: Sorry, bad english.
Is it possible to use:
<match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="queue=myQueue">
            <access method="list*" roles="myRole"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to restrict the addresses that a user can *see* in the tree structure on the left of the ActiveMQ Artemis web console. However, you can restrict whether or not a user in a specific role can see the attributes or perform management operations on specific addresses, e.g.:

```xml
<match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="address=&quot;test&quot;">
   <access method="*" roles="test"/>
</match>
```

This match ensures that only a user in the `test` role can manage the address named `test`.